# How can i navigate through frtagments and have fragments state and all views state the way they were when i navigate back using Databinding?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) to make handling views and binding data to them easy for myself and i also use [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation). Evething works fine but i can not save fragments'(destination) UI state. For example if i have a recyclerview and i scroll to last position and i navigate to another fragment and when i get back to previous fragment, i can see first recyclerview's position. Now, it's either databinding scrolled recyclerview to first position or recyclerview is recreated. First i thought it's because of navigation component that does not save destinatins views state so i read with more attention and i reached [navigate to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#savestate) which in [popUpToSaveState and restoreSaveState](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#savestate) section says:

> When you use app:popUpTo to navigate to a destination, Navigation 2.4.0-alpha01 and higher allow you to optionally save the states of all destinations popped off of the back stack. To enable this option, include `app:popUpToSaveState="true"` in the associated  element:

so in all my `action`s i added `app:popUpToSaveState="true"` but did not solve my issue. So i kept reading and i faced this title about [support multiple back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/multi-back-stacks). In section of restoring state it says:

> Navigation XML
> In Navigation XML,  elements in your navigation graph can use the `app:popUpToSaveState` attribute to save the state of any destinations that the action popped using app:popUpTo. They can also use the app:restoreState attribute to restore any previously saved state for the destination defined in the app:destination attribute.

so i also add `app:restoreState="true"` to all my `actions`s but did not saved destinations(fragments) views state. so i realized it's not the navigation component that causes this problem it might be `databinding` that does not save fragments state. So i read more about databinding. Nothing attract my attention except this title [Bind layout views to Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture) and i saw this sample code:

```
class ViewModelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class.
    UserBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.user);

    // Specify the current activity as the lifecycle owner.
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
}
  }
```

so i thought i did not `Specify fragments as the lifecycle owners` and i added `binding.setLifecycleOwner(LIFE_CYCLER_OWNER);` to all fragment that i used databinding.

Here is how use databinding in fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_season_lists, container, false);
    fragBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    return fragBinding.getRoot();
}
```

and here is how i use databinding in recyclerview:

```
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
public SectionDataRecyclerView(
        Context context,
        ArrayList<SingleModel> sectionList) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.sectionList = sectionList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final ActivitySingleCourseListBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.activity_single_course_list, parent, false, null);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(binding.getLifecycleOwner());
    return new SectionDataRecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding);
}
```

I used both `this;` And `getViewLifecycleOwner()` for `binding.setLifecycleOwner(LIFE_CYCLE_OWNER);` in fragments but non of them saved views state like recyclerview position. To make sure it is the databinding that does not save states i created and test fragment with a recyclerview it and `RecyclerView.Adapter` in the exsisting navigation component without using databinding. it turned out that it's because of databinding that fragments are (let's say) recreating views so they can not have their state saved. It got too long so i ask my question in another way:

**Question :**

In case if using both `navigation component` and `databinding` how can i navigate through frtagments and have fragments state and all views state the way they were when i navigate back?

Comment: Are you [saving the state of your fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) across configuration changes and process death and recreation? If so, there's nothing else you need to do specific to the Navigation Component. If your fragment isn't saving its RecyclerView position correctly, that is a problem with that fragment, not with anything Navigation Component related. If you'd like help with how to save and restore your state of a particular fragment, please include all of the code for that fragment.

Comment: no i have not saved fragment sate across configuration changes and process death and i know it's not navigation component like i said. it actually is databinding that causes this problem. but the question is how can i use databinding and have my fragments states saved?